# Use Closure in Declaration to a Method (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, closures

I want to use a closure in the declaration to a method. The code can be written in `Swift` like this.

```
func request(whatever: String,
              success: ((AnyObject) -> Void)?,
              failure: ((NSError) -> Void)?) -> SomeClass {
         //Codes for this method.
}
```

How can I use closures in the method which gets `id` 
or `NSError` objects and returns nothing in `Objective-C`?

Comment: Are you calling the above function from Objective-C, or do you want to do the same thing as the above function in Objective-C?

Comment: Yes, I want to do the same thing as Swift codes. And the website helps me a lot. Thx~